# Satellite images align in QGIS but not in Python (rasterio)

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, polygon, coregistration

First time posting here. I'm working on my first remote sensing project to estimate forest structure attributes (e.g. forest height) using satellite images with deep learning. I've struggled for a while constructing the datasets for learning. Specifially, making sure the reference forest maps overlap the satellite images. QGIS actually shows the correct overlap after preprocessing (see picture 1). However, when I load the image in Python using `rasterio` each index (pixel) does not correspond the same pixel in the other images (see picture 2).

Why does QGIS show nearly perfect alignment while Python show a clear misalignment? Is there something wrong in the way I've preprocessed the image?

#### QGIS

Reference map (white to red gradient) overlaps background optical image nearly perfectly.

[image]

#### Python

The same images (left: optical, mid: sar, right: reference map) but accessing by the same indices (pixels) show different areas (by up to 50 pixels)

[image]

### Preprocessing steps

- Reprojecting - EPSG:4326 -> EPSG 32632

  - `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32632 -r lanczos -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -co COMPRESS=LZW opt.tif opt_reprojected.tif`
- Clipping - Clip all images according to a polygon that is an intersection between all images. See `clip_img_to_aoi()`
- Transforming - ​Manually fix the last misalignments between imgs

  - `gdalwarp -ct "+proj=affine +xoff=16 +yoff=0" opt.tif transformed_opt.tif`
- Resizing - Convert image to correct resolution and size (i.e. numpy shape). See `resize_img()`

> Post-processing Rasterio Stats
>
> Ground Truth (Reference map)
> (1, 8904, 11801)
> EPSG:32632
> Affine:
> | 0.50, 0.00, 290779.00|
> | 0.00,-0.50, 6809696.50|
> | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
>
> Opt
> (4, 8904, 11801)
> EPSG:32632
> Affine:
> | 0.50, 0.00, 290778.15|
> | 0.00,-0.50, 6809677.65|
> | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|

---

###### Clip image to area of interest

```
def clip_img_to_aoi(img_path, aoi_path='data/aoi.geojson'):
    with rasterio.open(img_path) as img_ds:
        with fiona.open(aoi_path) as geo:
            aoi = [feature["geometry"] for feature in geo]
        img_clipped, img_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(img_ds, aoi, crop=True)
        meta = img_ds.meta.copy()
        meta.update({"transform": img_transform,
            "height":img_clipped.shape[1],
            "width":img_clipped.shape[2]})
        with rasterio.open(img_ds.name[:-4] + '_clipped.tif', 'w', **meta) as f:
            f.write(img_clipped)
```

###### Resize image to appropriate resolution and shape

```
def resize_img(SAT_img, from_res, to_res):
    factor = to_res / from_res
    shape = (np.round(SAT_img.shape[1] / factor).astype(int) , np.round(SAT_img.shape[2] / factor).astype(int))
    SAT_image_resized = np.zeros((SAT_img.shape[0], shape[0], shape[1]))
    for channel in range(0, SAT_img.shape[0]):
        print("Resizing channel ", channel)
        SAT_image_resized[channel, :, :] = resize(SAT_img[channel, :, :], (shape[0], shape[1]), anti_aliasing=True)
    return SAT_image_resized

def change_meta_data(meta_data, factor):
    meta_dataNew = meta_data
    meta_dataT = meta_dataNew['transform']
    meta_dataNew['transform'] = Affine(meta_dataT[0] * factor, meta_dataT[1], meta_dataT[2], \
                                       meta_dataT[3], meta_dataT[4] * factor, meta_dataT[5])
    meta_dataNew['width'] = np.round(meta_data['width'] / factor).astype(int)
    meta_dataNew['height'] = np.round(meta_data['height'] / factor).astype(int)
    return meta_dataNew
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself. The culprit seemed to be the polygon (area of interest). There was a small edge that was hard to notice which extended beyond the optical image a few pixels. Recreating the shape to a ***true intersection*** of all the images fixed the issue.